# How to use IBM X-Force Exchange API?

Tags: java, http

I have wasted more than 5 hours on it documentation website. Nothing works.

An example will the following. 
curl -u {apikey:password} https://api.xforce.ibmcloud.com/url/cnn.com

It keeps saying that  {"error":"Not authorized."}

After replacing apikey and password with the value of the generated key and password I get this

C:\Downloads>curl -u {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY} GET https://api.xforce.ibmcloud.com/url/cnn.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: GET
{"error":"Not authorized."}

My plan is to be able to achieve the same result using JAVA but I cannot even get its most basic curl steps to work

Answer (score 1):

I also came to the same problem. The solution is removing "{}" for token, and then it should work.

In your case, the right command is

> curl -u
>   XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY
>   GET https://api.xforce.ibmcloud.com/url/cnn.com